# Вызов из Java bat файла и ожидание когда он завершится

Tags: java, bat

Есть задача, надо вызвать из java последовательно два раза один и тот же bat файл. 
Собственно решение которое я тут уже нашел

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c FullFileName.bat");
```

Проблема в том что надо сделать так, что бы не допустить что бы запустился второй раз bat afqk пока не окончит работать первый. Конструкция

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c FullFileName.bat").waitFor();
```

к сожалению не помогает. Собственно вопрос - куда копать?

UPDATE
из bat файла у меня дергается другая программа (Oracle forms). Когда запускаю bat файл из командной строки я четко вижу что bat файл ждет завершения работы внешней программы. А вот когда из java полное ощущение что не ждет. Потому что результат второй программы зачастую затирает результат работы первой программы.
Если принудительно ставить задержку то все ок

Comment: А собственно, почему waitFor не помогает? Этот метод ждет, пока процесс завершиться и возвращает код возврата.

Comment: @AndrewBystrov ну вот я тоже так думал, однако реальность оказалась зла... из bat файла  у меня дергается другая программа (Oracle forms). Когда запускаю bat файл из командной строки я четко вижу что bat файл ждет завершения работы внешней программы. А вот когда из java как то все не очевидно выходит...

Comment: А у вас в батнике кроме вызова oracle forms происходит что-то другое?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov да, переносится файл из одного места в другое

Comment: можете попробовать использовать методы для захвата монитора (блокирования потока) наподобие wait() notify()